# why my JPA annotated classes are not discovered implicitly?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My `persistence.xml` looks like:

```
<persistence>
  <persistence-unit name="test">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.XXX.Abc</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="true" />
      ..
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
<persistence>
```

Everything works fine. When I'm removing `<class>` directive I'm getting an exception from `EntityManager.find(Abc.class, 1)`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.XXX.Abc
```

Looks like hibernate can't discover my annotated classes although I'm using `@Entity`.. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of the `hibernate.archive.autodetection` is a csv list of elements that are autodiscovered by hibernate.

Try this instead:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
```

---

**Further Reading**

- [Hibernate Community Documentation, 2.2.2 - Bootstrapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-bootstrapping) (has a table with properties documentation)

Comment: class is enough i think for his case.no hbm required

Answer (score 1):

Try Making it..like this

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
```

[Documentations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Hibernate looks for classes in the same codesource as the persistence.xml. So, for example, if you have persistence.xml in a folder and classes in a separate jar, Hibernate won't find them.